# Лампочки в очереди проверок теперь есть, только вот светят без повода

Tags: дефект, очередь-проверок

[image]

Comment: И ещё https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFWGh.png

Comment: Лампочки (как и старые счетчики) в меню - общие для всех участников. В очереди на закрытие сейчас 430+ вопросов, просто вы их все или пропустили, или часть из них сами добавили в очередь.

Comment: @PashaPash старые счётчики писали у меня нули. И я не хочу видеть лампочку зазря, я специально для этого (и для обнуления счётчиков) почти всё пропустил)

Comment: ну вот теперь страдайте! :)

Comment: Жуткие лампочки.

Comment: Вероятно, лампочка не учитывает частные кол-ва, отображаемые на странице всех очередей. В этом случае, стало хуже, чем раньше. Но хочу заметить, что я с подобным не сталкивался. Видимо, имеет значение значение репутации. У Вас голоса на закрытие вообще бывают не 0?

Comment: @alexolut бывают, я специально всё к нулю свёл) Сейчас протыкал 12 вопросов, некоторые закрыл, некоторые пропустил — стало снова ноль, но лампочка горит

Comment: Вам всё же некоторая ограниченная очередь показывается, как уже говорил @PashaPash. У меня сейчас [так](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0uhAw.jpg), например.

Comment: Ну пару недель назад у меня было около 250, если что

Comment: @andreymal интересно, это получается, что все сообщения в очереди Вами уже были обработаны, так что ли? За пару недель можно 280 обработать.

Comment: @alexolut собсна об этом я и говорю. Только больше половины пропущено

Comment: Ну, тогда @PashaPash [всё правильно сказал](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5978/%d0%9b%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%87%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%8c-%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%be-%d0%b2%d0%be%d1%82-%d1%81%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%8f%d1%82-%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%b7-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0#comment22868_5978) :D

Comment: Запилил вопрос на [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/301576/339911) по похожей ситуации, но с очередью сообщений низкого качества.