# Верните счётчики очередей в выпадающем списке

Tags: предложение, очередь-проверок

Цветную точку можно тоже оставить, но счётчики нужны.
Без них не хочется в проверку заходить :(

Comment: где метка [tag:нытье] ?

Comment: Да-да, хотел аналогичную просьбу писать, но решил не ныть)

Answer (score 6):

Любое изменение интерфейса - это стресс для конечного пользователя. Он должен к нему привыкать, менять свои привычки и алгоритмы взаимодействия с этим интерфейсом. Поэтому для подобных изменений необходимы очень веские причины (например запрос от самих пользователей) и тщательный анализ. И в любом случае следует всеми силами избегать ухудшения юзабилити и изменений ради изменений.

В истории с индикаторами вместо счетчиков лично я не вижу улучшений от слова совсем. Наоборот, стало менее удобно.

Почему лично для меня счетчики удобней.

Вот смотрите, у меня в среднем уходит по пол минуты на одну проверку. Т.е. если я вижу цифру больше 20 - я сразу прикидываю, что минут 10 чистого времени это займет. Если у меня сейчас есть эти 10 минут - я возьмусь за разбор, если нет - я возьму другую очередь, где, например, всего 5 ожидающих сообщений, а к большой очереди вернусь потом. При этом, взять длинную очередь и бросить разбор на половине банально вызывает у меня дискомфорт. В случае с маркерами я вижу абсолютно ни о чем не говорящие цветные кружочки и конкретику я могу получить только открыв новую страницу с очередью.

В любом случае никаких разумных доводов замены счетчиков метками(а точнее просто удалению счетчиков) я не увидел. Попытки объяснить вызывают ощущение натягивания шарика на кактус - мы сделали, давайте теперь придумаем зачем.

Comment: Как же Вы в модераторы-то собрались с такими фобиями перед очередями?

Comment: @alexolut дело не в фобиях, а в здравом смысле и грамотном распределении времени. С точки зрения здравого смысла не было никаких причин заменять понятные всем счетчики маркерами со спорной информативностью. А с точки зрения распределения времени мне бы хотелось представлять, сколько у меня его уйдет на обработку очереди до начала процесса. Ну вот сложно мне работу на половине бросать.

Comment: нет никакого бросать наполовину. Вы либо проверяете очередь и помогаете её уменьшать, либо нет и этим занимаются другие. К тому же, очередь не блокируется в монопольный доступ и одновременно её могут разгребать несколько участников, а значит она может закончиться раньше, чем вы того хотели. Да и нельзя заранее знать сколько времени уйдет на проверку одного элемента, так как сообщения, требующие проверки, могут быть существенно разного объёма и затрагивать как знакомые, так и не знакомые вам технологии. Именно поэтому есть еще и фильтр в очередях по меткам и причинам, например.

Comment: @alexolut вот смотрите, у меня `в среднем` уходит по пол минуты на одну проверку. Т.е. если я вижу цифру больше 20 - я сразу прикидываю, что минут 10 чистого времени это займет. Если у меня сейчас есть эти 10 минут - я возьмусь за разбор, если нет - я возьму другую очередь, где, например, всего 5 ожидающих сообщений, а к большой очереди вернусь потом. При этом, взять длинную очередь и бросить разбор на половине банально вызывает у меня дискомфорт. Беда в том, что вместо того, чтобы услышать собеседника вы оправдываете очень спорное решение в стиле, сильно утрируя, "не нравится? до свиданья"

Comment: В чем смысл предпочитать обнуление одной очереди уменьшению другой, но без обнуления? Пока вы делаете проверку, могут появиться новые задачи, и вы так же не уложитесь в отведённое время.

Comment: @alexolut в психологии. `При этом, взять длинную очередь и бросить разбор на половине банально вызывает у меня дискомфорт.` В случае длинной очереди я буду уверен, что мне придется прерваться на середине. В случае короткой очереди я буду уверен, что завершу проверку за +- конкретное время, с удовлетворением посмотрю на надпись "Очередь кончилась" и продолжу работать с чувством выполненного долга. В любом случае я не вижу ни одного плюса от замены счетчиков метками(точнее даже от удаления счетчиков), а минусы описал.

Comment: плюсы я описал в своем ответе. С развитием сайта очереди будут только расти, так что единолично не получится ее обнулить, у нас это пока что очередь на закрытие, но на enSO таких больше. К тому же, всё равно есть суточный лимит, по достижении которого вам говорят спасибо, приходите завтра.

Comment: Пустая очередь при красном индикаторе — это [баг](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/301576/339911).

Comment: @alexolut при Брежневе такого не было (с) Ну, в смысле, что не помню таких косяков со счетчиками ;)

Answer (score -5):

Счётчики в меню не нужны. Если возникает желание узнать действительный размер очередей, это всегда можно на [странице всех очередей](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review) (ссылка доступна из меню). Таким образом, дозирование информации — сначала общий индикатор в верхней панели, потом индикаторы по доступным очередям, а далее, при желании, числа — лучший вариант, нежели вываливание всех значений сразу. По сути, если очередь не пуста, то не так важно сколько там элементов для проверки, особенно если есть индикатор, показывающий чему стоит отдать приоритет. Не будете же вы ждать какого-то конкретного значения, прежде чем начать проверку.

[Исследование](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/355234/3240681) показало бОльшую эффективность обработки очередей при наличии индикаторов, нежели чисел. К тому же индикатор в первую очередь показывает, где ваши проверки наиболее востребованы для сайта в целом. Не нужно искать, куда бы податься сначала. Видишь красный — действуй!

И если вам не хочется заходить в очередь, не видя цифр, то у кого-то могут быть и обратные ситуации. Например: вижу *большое* число —не пойду в очередь, так как мои проверки ничего не изменят в общем случае, а мне бы хотелось «обнулить» очередь; вижу *маленькое* число — не пойду, так как и без меня справятся.

Comment: У меня могут быть свои представления, чему отдать приоритет и по каким причинам. Ну и на отдельную страницу за этой информацией ходить лень.

Comment: @Qwertiy в вопросе речь исключительно о счётчиках — какие тут могут быть причины, кроме как построенные на абсолютном значении элементов в очереди?

Comment: До тех пор, пока страница не перегружена, лучше вываливание всех значений сразу. Я сам разберусь, что, как и когда мне читать, без всяких принудительных «дозирований» со стороны сайта. К тому же [с учётом странной логики работы лампочек](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5978) всплывашка сейчас оказывается вообще бесполезна

Comment: @andreymal баги в реализации — это совершенно другой момент, их просто следует исправить. Ну и что считать перегруженность — момент достаточно субъективный.

Comment: @alexolut поэтому в настройках нужны галочки «Показывать лампочки» и «Показывать счётчики»)) Но такого не будет(

Comment: @andreymal кастомизация интерфейса не очень в почете на SO, только уж если очень желания разойдутся, сделают. Как например с липучестью топбара.