# Паразитная правка при установке сообщению статуса «общий»

Tags: дефект, правки, общие-сообщения

Всего лишь сделал [сообщение](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6063/176217) «общим», однако в [списке ревизий](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/6063/revisions) почему-то сказано о добавлении каких-то 8 символов.

> [image: восемь символов]

На диффе ничего такого не видно.

Случай номер два: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/4101/revisions

Номер три: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/5710/revisions